# Strong typing a loop variable

Tags: powershell, loops, strong-typing

I have been refactoring an app from functions and some bad scripting habits to classes and better habits, including strong typing of all my variables. And on that front I wonder what the "right" answer is for a foreach loop.

So, with dynamic typing I can do

```
foreach ($i in 1..100) {}
```

for example. But my first thought on how to type that `$i` variable was...

```
foreach ([int32] $i in 1..100) {}
```

but you can't do that. The other thought I had was...

```
[Int32] $i = $null
foreach ($i in 1..100) {}
```

and that works. It seems a little silly for this example, but for something like...

```
foreach ($filePath in $filePaths) {}
```

strong typing `$filePath` as `[String]` alerts you when you have populated `$filePaths` with file objects rather than simple string paths, for example. So, it seems to make sense. But none of this shows up much in examples on the interwebs, where most things are more script focused. So, when committing to strong typing, is this the way to go, or is this overkill and an iteration variable is one of those places where just letting PowerShell handle the dynamic typing is acceptable?

Comment: Why type in the loop vs using pre-declaration? Using the `Set-StrictMode` [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode), in your developing instances will also help with code consistency.  The deal is really all about consistency and avoid surprises down the line. As an old dev, I've always adhered to the declare, as well as apply needed attributes, before use mantra. [See also](http://blog.matticus.net/2015/03/powershell-identifying-strongly-or.html).

Comment: For loop variables strong typing doesn't give you much IMO. You normally *want* the type of the loop variable to match the type of the collection elements. If you are consistent with strong typing for e. g. function arguments you'll catch errors soon enough, when the loop variable is actually used.

Comment: This seems to work: `foreach ($i in [Int32] 1..100) {}`

Comment: See also: [Strongly Encouraged Development Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/strongly-encouraged-development-guidelines?view=powershell-7.1) --- [Creating Strongly Typed Objects In PowerShell, Rather Than Using An Array Or PSCustomObject](https://blog.danskingdom.com/creating-strongly-typed-objects-in-powershell-rather-than-using-an-array-or-pscustomobject) --- [How to Write Beautiful PowerShell Code using Best Practices](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-best-practices)

Comment: Programming/Coding is all about standardization, not necessarily the language. Though you are bound by the language specifics. I recommend this book regulalry. [Code Complete: A Practical Handbook of Software Construction, Second Edition 2nd Edition](https://www.amazon.com/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=code+complete&qid=1616011555&sr=8-1)

Comment: What is your motivation for imposing strong typing everywhere? Are you trying to solve a particular class of problems that have bit you before? If you impose strong typing everywhere else (eg. `[string[]]$filepaths`), then this is entirely unnecessary

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen, I am just trying to implement strong typing in general, and "right". So, sounds like you are saying that when one variable is derived directly from another one that IS strongly typed, then the derived one doesn't need to be. Or more correctly it is indirectly. It does suggest that as you say `$filesPaths` should be `[string[]]`, not Array, so I can be 100% certain of what type a member is. THAT is the light bulb that just went off as I read your comment. :)

Comment: @postanote Code Complete, along with the Clean Code books and The Pragmatic Programmer have all been on my list for ages. It may be time to suck it up and go to school. :)